# DataTable bound to WPF DataGrid Validation in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, datatable

I am working on app and part of it is:

1. load data from SQL database to DataTable (in ViewModel);
2. provide DataTable data to user (in View) using binding to DataGrid ItemsSource;
3. user can edit/add/remove rows via DataGrid - **all changes have to be validated**
4. Table is stored back to Database

I struggle with data validation of edited row. I tried [following techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/june/msdn-magazine-input-validation-enforcing-complex-business-data-rules-with-wpf) but each has some flaw:

1. Exception/IDataErrorInfo - not sure where to implemented these as DataTable/TableRow is predefined class - I am not able to simply insert it into TableRow setter, Am I?. (I am able to monitor user changes using DataTable events (RowChanged etc.).)
2. ValidationRule - this disturbs MVVM model as I need to check if inserted values are already in database - rules are not static
3. Set RowError in RowChanged event - this is probably something different as Validation

I've just really briefly sketched out tried solutions - I am able to provide source code for any of them.

My question is: what's the best approach to data validation in this case?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear - I will fix it.